# What parameters do I need to put into InsertOnSubmit(...) if one or more of my columns is an identity column?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

My table was created with

```
CREATE TABLE orgs ( orgid int NOT NULL identity(1,1), orgname nvarchar (MAX) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (orgid) );
```

and my C# class that mirrors it is

```
[Table(Name = "orgs")]
public class Organization
{
    public Organization()
    {

    }

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey=true)]
    public int orgid { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string orgname { get; set; }
}
```

However, when I issue the calls

```
        PD.orgs.InsertOnSubmit(new Organization { orgname = newOrgName });

        try
        {
            PD.SubmitChanges();
        } // try submitting to db
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Content(e.Message, "text/html");
        }
```

I learn that

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'orgs' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

This confuses me because I thought it was equivalent to issuing the direct SQL  command

```
INSERT INTO orgs (orgname) VALUES ('something');
```

and yet I don't get an error when I do that.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
[Table(Name = "orgs")]
public class Organization
{
    public Organization()
    {

    }


    [Column(IsDbGenerated=true)]
    public int orgid { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string orgname { get; set; }
}
```

change ur class like this and check

Comment: That works! But don't I need `[Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]` or is the `IsPrimaryKey=true` unnecessary?

Comment: @downvoter can u pls tell what the issue here?

Comment: It's still the primary key. Note the documentation says "If the column holds primary key values and you designate IsDbGenerated as true, you should also add the DbType property by using the IDENTITY modifier."

Comment: @stuartd since it is orgid int NOT NULL identity(1,1) no need to specify primary key..it will be autogenerated and will be primary

Comment: @Sachu the IsPrimaryKey docs say "Assuming an entity class, you must provide at least one member with this attribute, and it must be mapped to the primary key or a unique key in the corresponding table or view. Failure to do this prompts LINQ to SQL to consider instances of the class as read-only for submitting changes to the database."

Comment: @stuartd ok agree but [Column(IsDbGenerated=true)] statement is needed else class will consider it as off thats why he is getting the error

Comment: @FiredfromAmazon.com if it solved ur issue can u please upvote it?

Comment: @Sachu yes, I just upvoted you. Thanks for your help.